# Matching regular expression only at beginning of line in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a string that spans multiple lines. The line breaks are LF, as in this example of "hello world" that has a line break between "hello" and "world":

```
some_bytes = [104  101  108  108  111 10 119  111  114  108  100];
some_string = char(some_bytes);

disp(some_string)
```

I want to match the sequence "wo", but only if it occurs at the beginning of a line. But using the regular expression

```
idx = regexpi(some_string,'^wo');
```

returns an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`^`, by default, matches only at the beginning of the string. You can activate multiline mode by using the `(?m)` search flag:

```
idx = regexpi(some_string,'(?m)^wo');
```

Alternatively, you can supply the option `'lineanchors'`. [See the documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/regexpi.html#inputarg_expression).